# How to return column containing text and other column values in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012 and I have a table `Accounts`:

```
  [ClientId] | [AccNumber] | [AccBalance]
```

This query works fine:

```
   SELECT TOP 5
        [ClientId]
        ,[AccNumber]
        ,[AccBalance]
   FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Accounts]
```

But all these are columns which the table `Accounts` contains. Now I want to add another column which will return something that eventually should look like a short text describing each account.

Or to be more clear I tried to add this:

```
  SELECT TOP 5
      [ClientId]
      ,[AccNumber]
      ,[AccBalance]
      ,('Client Number = ' + [ClientId] + 'Account Number = ' + [AccNumber] + 'Account Balance = ' + [AccBalance]) as txt
  FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Accounts]
```

However when I try to execute this in SQL Server Management Studio, I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Client Number = '
>   to data type int.

Is there a way to make this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't automagically convert `INT` or `DECIMAL` to string - you need to do this explicitly:

```
 SELECT TOP 5
      [ClientId]
      ,[AccNumber]
      ,[AccBalance]
      ,('Client Number = ' + CAST([ClientId] AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
        'Account Number = ' + CAST([AccNumber] AS VARCHAR(20)) + 
        'Account Balance = ' + CAST([AccBalance] AS VARCHAR(20)) as txt
  FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Accounts]
```

If you don't explicitly specify anything, T-SQL will try to convert everything to the highest ranking datatype - and `INT` is "more important" (higher ranked) than `VARCHAR`, so T-SQL will try to convert your string literals into `INT` (which obviously fails)

See the [MSDN docs on datatype precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) for a full list of how the datatypes are ranked

Comment: Gratitude. You are one of the few `SQL` pro's that I recognize here. It's always pleasure when I have the chance to get an answer from you. +1 and Accept from me!

Answer (score 1):

This is due to (i'm assuming) your clientId, accNumber, accBalance (or any combination of them) being of type int.  You could accomplish what you need by:

```
  SELECT TOP 5
   [ClientId]
  ,[AccNumber]
  ,[AccBalance]
  ,('Client Number = ' + convert(varchar(50), [ClientId]) + 'Account Number = ' + convert(varchar(50),[AccNumber]) + 'Account Balance = ' + convert(varchar(50),[AccBalance])) as txt
  FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[Accounts]
```

as an example.

Another (I would argue better) approach would be to do this on the UI, as all of the information to build out the string is already located within your row/object.